# How to prohibit Key Press during a method in Java application?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm making an application with JavaFX and Scene Builder. I have a method that make animation of Anchor Pane. Translate transition and rotate transition.

When I press "1" on keyboard that method is called.

> The problem is when I press on key 1 so fast animation works
>   incorrectly. It seems when I press too fast on a key animation of
>   Anchor Pane is shifted.

**How can I prohibit key press during animation or how can I set a delay between key presses?**

Controller:

```
@FXML  private AnchorPane randomCard;

@FXML public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {    

//key commands
mainAnchor.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
  switch (event.getCode()) {       
    case DIGIT1:          
      showRandomCard();
      break;
  }
});

//show random card in main window
 private void showRandomCard(){

    TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition();
    tt.setDuration(Duration.millis(400));
    tt.setNode(randomCard);
    tt.setFromY(950);
    tt.setFromX(-600);
    tt.setToY(0);
    tt.setToX(0);        

    RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(500), randomCard);
    rt.setByAngle(360);
    rt.setRate(1);
    rt.setCycleCount(1);        

    tt.play();       
    rt.play();

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `boolean` field and use the `onFinished` handler of the animation that finishes last to reset it to a state that allows execution of the logic for creating/starting the animations:

```
private boolean animationRunning = false;
private void showRandomCard(){
    if (!animationRunning) {
        animationRunning = true;
        TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition();
        tt.setDuration(Duration.millis(400));
        tt.setNode(randomCard);
        tt.setFromY(950);
        tt.setFromX(-600);
        tt.setToY(0);
        tt.setToX(0);

        RotateTransition rt = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(500), randomCard);
        rt.setByAngle(360);
        rt.setRate(1);
        rt.setCycleCount(1);
        rt.setOnFinished(evt -> animationRunning = false);

        tt.play();
        rt.play();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanx! it helped me!